# MySQL select one row from field WHERE condition is in multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Tried to find the answer, but still couldn't.. The table is as follows:

```
  name,    room_chat
  Ratna          2
  Ima            2
  Ratna          3
  Yanis          3
```

i need something like this
if i `select name from table where (name='Ratna' and name='Ima')` i get a result

```
room chat
2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several rows, but you want to look at a set of rows. This is called aggregation. In your case you want to look at each room chat, so you `group by room_chat`. You want to know whether for a room chat you find both names, so count the names.

The query:

```
select room_chat
from table 
where name in ('Ratna','Ima')
group by room_chat
having count(distinct name) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use in clause as below:

```
select distinct a.room_chat from tableA a where a.name in ('Ratna', 'Ima')
```

Comment: i have tried like this, but the result is chat_room = 2,2,3 not only the result '2' in one rows